# Why does redeclaring std::cout cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am testing C++ with this code. I compiled with GCC version 8.3.0, on Ubuntu version 18.10.

```
#include <ostream>
namespace std{
    extern ostream cout;
};
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

The code was compiled without problems. However, when executing, the program print out:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Why is that?

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, it doesn't always compile without problems: https://wandbox.org/permlink/O34BRDuS4xwAjw1P

Comment: `namespace std{
    extern ostream cout;
};` - No. You cannot do that. The *only* thing a program is allowed to add to the `std` namespace is template specializations.

Comment: "The code was compiled without problems" - That means next to nothing. A *lot* of incorrect code in C++ does *not* require the compiler to issue a diagnostic. There are a lot of things that you are not allowed to do, and if you do them anyway the compiler is absolved of all obligations and may generate *whatever* code it wants. The only way to avoid that is to know all the rules and not write invalid code. And yes, there are *many* rules and many pitfalls - C++ is *difficult*.

Comment: To be fair, the reason that this particular violation of the standard contract resulted in this particular practical outcome, could be interesting. At first glance one might reasonably expect a simple redeclaration to work. From me: +1 and a title improvement.

Comment: @Bob__ Your example compiles without problems.

Comment: If you tell us what your compiler (including version) and platform are, we could probably work this out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed. Why the compiler chose to do what it did with this source could be interesting to figure out. Got a +1 from me as well - it's not a bad question and there's a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the compiler version in the question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough, my wording wasn't correct.

Comment: The output of this shows the differences in symbol binding by the dynamic linker: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c489e6777790e77

Comment: “The correct code should be” `#include <iostream>`.  Don’t make up your own declarations for the standard library.

Comment: If you found a different explanation please go ahead and write an answer. Don't put answers in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we've already covered that your program has undefined behaviour, because you're not allowed to declare things in namespace `std` like this. Only the toolchain is allowed.

Usually when your program has UB, as with reading some random part of memory or confusing the optimiser, all bets are off and we don't even bother trying to work out *why* we saw some particular outcome. However, in this instance it's a little simpler than that.

In libstdc++v3 (which is what you're using), for example, depending on certain configurations [the actual stream declarations](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/iostream) are [in namespace `std::__8`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/c%2B%2Bconfig) for versioning reasons, where `__8` is an inline namespace. Your `extern` declaration isn't, so it does not match the real, original declarations. This can result in [a linker error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O34BRDuS4xwAjw1P), as the newly-added declaration doesn't actually marry up to any object that exists.

In other configurations, [conflicting visibility settings](https://labjack.com/news/simple-cpp-symbol-visibility-demo) on the declaration can confuse the linker still further and result in segmentation faults at runtime.
The only way to really be sure what the original declaration looks like for you would be to observe the preprocessed source of the program `#include <iostream>` on your computer (which is not hard to do; use `g++ -E`!) and see how it ended up for your particular configuration.

The moral of the story is that, although browsing cppreference.com would have you believe that `cout` begins its life as a simple:

```
namespace std {
   ostream cout(/* some args */);
}
```

… the reality is often more complicated, and your redeclaration does not consider any of the complications, and some of those complications can violate the rules in a way that produces the results you've observed.

Comment: Okay so I'm hedging my bets a little on the details, but I stand by the main points

Comment: The compiler emits a relocation entry for references to data within code. Since the global variable was not defined, the linker should complain. In this case, the linker somehow didn't complain and the relocation wasn't done, therefore leaving an undefined address being used in the machine code (my guess is that it used PC-relative addressing, and it ended up trying to write to the machine code (read-only!), while trying to write something to the `std::cout` object).

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't mean "global variable" but wrote it. I was refering to std::cout. Thinking more about it, the libstdc++ library must contain both `std::cout` *and* `std::__v8::cout`, because `-fabi-version` is a compile/link-time option. Therefore, I can imagine the dynamic linker successfully resolves his declaration of `std::cout` to the "old"-ABI `std::cout` definition. But because other structures in his program were compiled to use the new ABI, this causes compatibility problems (for example, the instantiation of `std::basic_ostream` uses the new ABI version). So it crashes.

Comment: Hm, looks like I was fooled with the `-fabi-version`. It refers to the language ABI, like name mangling. Not to the libstdc++ ABI version. Not sure whether the libstdc++ actually contains both ABIs then, but it would sound like a waste of space.